# Filter ng-repeat based on search input with transformation filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of records and I'm repeating on a HTML table with filters in the header. It turns out that some values are transformed by filters thus making the ng-repeat filter to fail.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input ng-model="search.time" type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter: search">
      <td>{{record.time | timeFormatter}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you guys can see, the value in the table column is being transformed by the timeFormatter filter. So, instead of "0800", it shows "08:00 AM" for the record time. When the user types "08" it works, but if they type "08:", or "AM" it doesn't work anymore.

Can you guys help me to make the filter work with the values as they are displayed in the table column (i.e with formatting)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show the code in the timeFormatter filter.

Comment: I've just created this codepen to help you guys understand what I need.. https://codepen.io/marcioferlan/pen/PGjxya

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to play with a directive.  Try this:

```
    angular.module("app").directive("myDirective", function(){
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
          //convert data from view format to model format
           return input.substring(0, 2) + ':' + input.substring(2)
        });

        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          //convert data from model format to view format
         return input.substring(0, 2) + ':' + input.substring(2)
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBmg5xWdJW5lWjsxpFtQ)

Answer (score 0):

This is just guess work, but your ng-model is storing changes on search.time, but your filter is 'filtering' search. Try using search.time in filter.

Comment: I used 'search' as the filtering variable because in my actual code, I have other fields the user can use to filter.. please check this codepen https://codepen.io/marcioferlan/pen/PGjxya